# Prevent postion from reset to 0.0.0 when serial goes offline

Tags: marlin, firmware

My hardware Arduino Mega with RAMPS 1.6 with Marlin 1.0.2 and powered by external power to prevent my board from losing memory, when I reconnect the USB and serial goes offline, the board set last position e.g 10,0,0 to 0,0,0 as x,y,z

How to prevent last position  from reset ?

Comment: Easy answer is to not reconnect the USB, maybe you need to explain why you reconnect.

Answer (score 2):

The problem not with marlin,
The board is reset by the Serial port DTR line going low and pulsing the Arduino reset pin,
You can prevent this if you can disable DTR on your PC or by removing the capacitor that connects the DTR Serial pin to the reset pin.